# How to approach development of such a tool in Dynamics CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have implemented the feature illustrated in the video http://screenr.com/LgS7 (Salesforce).

Now I need to the same in Dynamics CRM. I have been through many contents about Dynamics and I am getting familiar with it but still struggling to find my way through to complete this specific task.

How can I achieve such a time tracking tool in Dynamics CRM? Should I do it by creating a plugin, custom actions or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it only with Javascript and some ribbon buttons.

Here is an article that explains a bit JavaScript with Dynamics CRM. It's based on SOAP and REST.

[Use JavaScript with Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh771584.aspx)

The method I suggest is that you make 2 ribbon buttons equal to the buttons in your movie. and then add a JAvascript file containing the logic behind the buttons to the form of the entity you will be using.

Here is a link to add ribbon buttons to the ribbon in Dynamics CRM

[Visual ribbon Editor](http://crmvisualribbonedit.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Since Dynamics CRM is Microsoft I was kind of hoping to be able to use .NET. But it looks like ribbons only execute URLs and JavaScript. Disapointing for me but it will get the job done. Thanks mate!